# Send keys not working , right xpath and id (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, xpath

Tried sendomg keys , right relative xpath or ID used but still not working properly

Tried using absolute xpath , relative xpath also ID. Tried using selassist and chropath still not working. Could there be something preventing it?

```
public void LoginWebSystem() {              
    driver = new ChromeDriver();    
    driver.get("http://localhost:82");  
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("login_username"));
    email.sendKeys("superadmin");   
    System.out.println("Username Set"); 
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("login_password"));
    password.sendKeys("nelsoft121586"); 
    System.out.println("Password Set"); 
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit"));
    login.click();
    System.out.println("Login Button Clicked"); 
      String newUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        if(newUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("http://localhost:82/controlpanel.php")){
            System.out.println("Login Success");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
        }   

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Product")).click();
    System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Product Page");


    driver.findElement(By.id("createlink")).click();
    System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Create Product by Detailed");

    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    System.out.println("Successful in clicking alert button");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}

@Test (priority=1)
public void ProductDetails() {

    WebElement product = driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id="text-product"]"));
    product.sendKeys("superadmin");
```

}
}

Expected output should input superadmin to product textbox

Comment: Can you paste the HTML also? lets check if the element you are trying to `send_keys` to is editable or not? Also, please paste the error you are facing. Saying `not working` does not give any idea of what the problem can be.

Comment: Found out right ID or path but does not work because element might not have loaded yet , tried  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  and wait for it to load but still does not work

Comment: whats the error message? And please provide the HTML.. is element editable?

Comment: Check if there any `iframe` ?? if there then you need to switch to `iframe` first.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: please read [mcve] and make your question understandable. there could be many factors affecting your code, sharing all relevant information brings more good solutions to question, it has been asked you to provide html structure of element and you provided error :( , add the things like what you trying to achieve? where you stucked? question depends on other things like html structure of lelements, pom file, jar files, versions of selenium, language binding etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a typo in your XPath expression:

   ```
   WebElement product = driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id="text-product"]"));
                                                     ^ remove this space break
   ```
2. It's better to use [By.Id](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html) [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) where possible as this is the fastest and the most robust way of identifying elements in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)
3. Consider using [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that the element is present and can be interacted with as it might be the case the element becomes available after [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) becomes `complete`. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more detailed explanation.

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
           .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("text-product")))
           .click();
   ```
4. Make sure that your selector matches an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) because if the [id](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) belongs to other element type like [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) it doesn't make a lot of sense to send keys there.